# Change the string

Tags: regex, string, formatting

I have a string with the value as

> (ABC,XYZ)

Can you someone help suggest me on how to convert this into

> ('ABC','XYZ')

I tried to below format but it is coming as

> ''' + recordIds + '''

Result that I got:

> '(ABC, XYZ)'

Comment: what language do you use?

Comment: Actaully. I got the answer. I tried below format and it worked. String ids = recordIds.size() > 0 ? ('\'' + String.join(recordIds, '\',\'') + '\'') : '';

Comment: It is on Salesforce.

Comment: Use a global find `([^(),']+)` and replace `'$1'`

Answer (score 0):

You could match the following regular expression and replace it with `('$1','$2')`, where `$1` and `$2` are the contents of the two capture groups.

```
\(([A-Z]+),([A-Z]+)\)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oI7PpF/3/)

The following operations are performed.

```
\(         : match '('
([A-Z]+)   : match 1+ capital letters and save to capture group 1
,          : match '('
([A-Z]+)   : match 1+ capital letters and save to capture group 2
\)         : match ')'
```